# Is it ok to use react-transition-group?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-transition-group

I've revived warnings from React when using react-transtion-group component (which is `Transition`) in `React.StrictMode` about

> legacy context API

in the Transition component. and

> findDOMNode is deprecated.

I intended to use react-transition-group on a big project but know I don't know. **Is the library still receiving updates & is it safe to use it ?**

and if it not, do you have any appropriate replacement ?

NOTE: I'm using the latest version of react `^16.8.4` and react-transition-group `^2.6.1`

NOTE2: [snapshot of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2gYa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just look on their github repo. The answer is yes, they're still updating it as of March 15 2018. I've used it recently and it was fine.

Comment: So they would probably update it to catch up with the new React standards. Great! I hope they'd update it soon

Answer (score 0):

late to answer this question.  But, you will need to use refs for your components if you are using react strict mode in your development environment.

You can read this explanation in the doc http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-nodeRef

It is likely that you are getting this error because you are using strict mode in development environment.

If you don't use strict mode, you will not see any issue.

Examples:with and without refs, https://github.com/nfabacus/react-transition-group-list-example/blob/main/README.md